# Formatting style for matplotlib: scatterplot histogram hybrid

Tags: python, matplotlib

In an old standalone plotting package (sm) there was a style available for scatter plots which I found more appealing to the general style. It appears as each point looking almost like a histogram which stretches to the next point.

**An example of a scatter plot using this style**:
[image: Example]

Matplotlib does have this style for histograms, but I'm wondering if there's a way to cheat the system to allow the style to work for scatter plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the confusion comes from the fact that the desired plot is *not* a scatter plot. It's a line plot with lines in form of a step-like function.

You may plot step functions with `pyplot.step(x,y)` or `plot(x,y, drawstyle="steps")`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

x = np.linspace(0,1)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.step(x,y)
# or
# ax.plot(x,y, drawstyle="steps")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah,  see. It would appear my vocabulary is lacking. Thanks for the help!